# Create External Partition Table GCP Bucket

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hive

We want to create external table on top of our GCP bucket where we store parquet data

Currently our Bucket is having this structure
`Buckets/ MY BUCKET / DATA /2020/07/11/`.  -- This location will have parquet  file

How we can create external table top of that where we can partition the table based on `year/month/date` format.
Parquet file contains filed `time` which has the required value
Sample Value- `2020-07-11T15:13:52.032Z`

I am using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE  if NOT EXISTS TESTING(
(   ID VARCHAR,
    SOURCE  varchar, 
    TIME  varchar 
)
PARTITIONED BY (TIME)
)
WITH (format = 'parquet', external_location = 'My Bucket Location')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pseudo column `_FILE_NAME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column) that provides you the full path of your file `gs://MY BUCKET/DATA/2020/07/11/filename`

You can do this

```
with part as (
select *,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, r"^.*/DATA/([0-9]{4})/.*") as year, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, r"^.*/DATA/[0-9]{4}/([0-9]{1,2})/.*") as month, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, r"^.*/DATA/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/([0-9]{1,2})/.*") as day)

select * 
from part
where year="2020" and month="07"
```

Or create a view and query only the view not the raw external table.